# Find and write to next blank cell in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to find and write to next blank cell.

[image]

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\\filepath\file.txt', 'r')  as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)

    with open (r'C:\filepath\file.csv', 'a', newline = '') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        for row in reader:
            content = [i.split('~') for i in row]
            for row1 in content:
                con = [len(k.split('*')) for k in row1]
                conn = [m.split('*') for m in row1]
                for b in conn:
                    if con[0] > 4:
                        if (b[0] == 'NM1' and b[1] == '82' and b[2] == '1' ):
                            writer.writerow([b[3]] + [b[4]])
                            print ( b[3] + b[4] )
                        elif (b[0] == 'GS' ):
                            writer.writerow(['','','',b[2]])
                            print(b[2])
```

Seeking to get the output as shown in pic above. Right now in the first row only 'App1' is printing then in second row the names etc.                            Input File I am using as below. :

```
ISA*16* 00 0*T*>~ 
GS*IN*APP1*0999~ 
HPT*1*2~ SE*21*0001~ 
GE*1*145~
NM1*82*1*Tiger1a*Test1*K****~ 
NM1*82*1*Lion1a*Test2*K****~ 
NM1*82*1*Elephant1a*Test3*K****~ 
ISA*16* 00 0*T*>~ 
GS*IN*APP2*0999~ 
HPT*1*2~ SE*21*0001~ 
GE*1*145~ 
NM1*82*1*Tiger1a*Test4*K****~
ISA*16* 00 0*T*>~ 
GS*IN*APP1*0999~ 
HPT*1*2~ 
SE*21*0001~ 
GE*1*145~ 
NM1*82*1*Tiger1a*Test4*K****~ 
NM1*82*1*Lion1a*Test5*K****~ 
NM1*82*1*Elephant1a*Test6*K****~ 
ISA*16* 00 0*T*>~ 
GS*IN*APP10999~ 
HPT*1*2~ 
SE*21*0001~ 
GE*1*145~ 
NM1*82*1*Tiger1a*Test7*K****~
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what exactly you're asking because of the formatting. Can you clean it up a little to make your input and output clearer?

Comment: @Chris comments remove all the formatting. You can edit your question instead.

Comment: Is the (rather strange) input you mention a product of an originally csv file? Or is the `~` and `*` separated data the original data you have to work with? In the case of the former, you can use for instance [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to parse your input in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume that you have an input file where `'~'` is a record separator and `'*'` is a field separator. As the csv module only deals with *lines* I would first use a generator to split the input file on `~`.

Then I would feed 2 lists, one with records starting with `NM1*82*1` and containing a list of the 2 following fields, one with records starting with `GS` containing one single field.

Finally I would add each line of the second list to the corresponding line in the first one.

Code could be:

```
def splitter(fd, sep):
"""Splits fd (assumed to be an input file object) on sep ignoring end of lines"""
    last = ""
    for line in fd:
        lines = line.strip().split(sep)
        lines[0] = last + lines[0]
        last = lines.pop()
        for l in lines:
            yield(l.strip())
    if last != "":
        yield last.strip()
    return

with open(r'C:\\filepath\file.txt', 'r')  as input_file, \
        open (r'C:\filepath\file.csv', 'a', newline = '') as output_file:
    rd = csv.reader(splitter(input_file, '~'), delimiter='*')
    wr = csv.writer(output_file)
    ls1 = []
    ls2 = []
    for b in rd:
        if b[0] == 'NM1' and b[1] == '82' and b[2] == '1':
            ls1.append([b[3], b[4]])
        elif b[0] == 'GS':
            ls2.append(b[2])
    for i, b in enumerate(ls2):
        ls1[i].append(b)
    wr.writerows(ls1)
```

I obtain:

```
Tiger1a,Test1,APP1
Lion1a,Test2,APP2
Elephant1a,Test3,APP1
Tiger1a,Test4,APP10999
Tiger1a,Test4
Lion1a,Test5
Elephant1a,Test6
Tiger1a,Test7
```

Answer (score -1):

Try reading the files into separate dictionary with lines numbers as keys. You can then iterate through both the dictionaries at the same time using zip function.

```
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```

More info here: [Python3 zip function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip)